# text not wrapping in right div

Tags: html, text, word-wrap

I have 2 divs in one container, but when I resize my browser, the right div does not wrap the text to fix the adjusted browser size. How can I get the right div to wrap the text?

[here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R8fXQ/)

```
#container {
    width: 498px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -150px; /* Half of width */
    margin-top: -50px;    /* Half of height */
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow: visible;
    padding-left:10px;
}

.left {
   float: left;
   width: 200px;
   text-align:left;
   word-wrap:break-word;
}

.right {
   float: right;
   width: auto;
   text-align:left;
   position:relative;
   word-wrap: break-word;
   overflow: auto;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
<div class="left">
<h3>For Students</h3>
  &#8226;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a  href="#savings-ambassador">Savings Ambassador</a><br>
  &#8226;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a  href="#appointment-coordinator">Appointment Coordinator</a><br>
  &#8226;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#savings-guru">Savings Guru</a>
  </div>
<div class="right">
<h3>For Graduates</h3>
  &#8226;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a  href="#director">Director, User Acquisition and Campus Events</a><br>
  &#8226;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a  href="#receptionist">Receptionist/PA</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is

```
.right {
      /* ... */
      width:auto;
      /* ... */
 }
```

because your `#container` has a given with from 498px. so if `.left{width} + .right{width}` is more than 498px your layout will break.

Here is a fiddle where .right width is 290px; (you could do 298px)  also .right can be floated to the left. (float right wan't work in older browsers..)

http://jsfiddle.net/R8fXQ/1/

Comment: I saw http://jsfiddle.net/R8fXQ/1/ and noticed that if I resize my browser, the text still does not wrap in the right div

Answer (score 0):

use the clear:both property

then use the float property and float one container to the right

the use the margin-right property

then use the padding property to make the containers meet each other and the use the text wrap property and set it to normal , and it should be ok.

Comment: please produce this code so I may see it in action (or I can copy/paste)